# 'TRIM' is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have created simple function

```
create function TRIM(@data varchar(20)) returns varchar(100)
as
begin
  declare @str varchar(20)
  set @str = rtrim(ltrim(@data))
  return @str
end
```

I am executing in the below way.

```
declare @s varchar(25)
set @s = '      Amru    '
select TRIM(@s)
```

I am getting the following error.

```
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 3
'TRIM' is not a recognized built-in function name.
```

Could any one please help me find the issue?

Comment: Did you try including the owner of the function (i.e. dbo.TRIM())?

Comment: more of an advanced topic: but using a udf like the one you've created tends to perform very badly...just a heads up.

Comment: Thanks all i got it.
@Mitch Wheat : I have faced above prob is because i am new to SQL

Comment: For Googlers: SQL Server does not have a TRIM function till 2017. This is about defining your own. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54340529/733092

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to use the Schema prefix when calling user defined functions. In your case this will most likely be "dbo".

Change your select statement to:

```
declare @s varchar(25)
set @s = '      Amru    '
select dbo.TRIM(@s)
```

Comment: For me using `dbo.TRIM` results in `Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.TRIM", or the name is ambiguous.`

Answer (score 30):

```
//use RTrim instead of Trim sql 2008
```

RTrim(ColumnName)

like this

```
select RTrim(a.ContactName) + ' ' + RTrim(a.City) as Name_City from customers as a
```

Answer (score 25):

```
declare @s varchar(25)
set @s = '      Amru    '
select RTRIM(LTRIM(@s))
```

You can use this way also without schema :)

Answer (score 0):

The error is that 'TRIM' is not a built-in function in SQL Server (as the error message suggests :) )

You can either wrap it with both LTRIM and RTRIM instead, or create your own TRIM function that does the same.

Comment: He's creating his own UDF called TRIM.

Comment: @Pearl, you haven't, the answer has.

Answer (score 0):

SQL server tries to parse `TRIM` as a built-in function. To call user-defined function you should put schema prefix in front of the function call. Try something like:

```
declare @s varchar(25)
set @s = '      Amru      '
select dbo.TRIM(@s)
```

Since `dbo`is a default schema prefix.

If you want to change your schema, declare the function as follow: (note the schema prefix in front of function name)

```
create function dbo.TRIM(@data varchar(20)) returns varchar(100)
as
begin
   --function body
end
```