# TRIM is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

For the following code:

```
DECLARE @ss varchar(60)
  SET @ss = 'admin'

  select TRIM(@ss)
```

I've got an error:

> 'TRIM' is not a recognized built-in function name

Comment: it is fine on my `SQL Server 2017`

Comment: Perhaps its set to an earlier compatibility level. Use this to find out: `SELECT compatibility_level FROM sys.databases`. It needs to be 140

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid you should post that as an answer.

Comment: You can use ltrim or rtrim

Comment: TRIM is in SQL Server (starting with 2017) so, none of these:        --SQL Server 2016 SQL Server 13 SQL Server 13.0 13.0.1601.5 
         --SQL Server 2014 SQL Server 12 SQL Server 12.0 codename Hekaton 12.0.2000.8 
         --SQL Server 2012 SQL Server 11 SQL Server 11.0 codename Denali 11.0.2100.60

Answer (score 124, accepted):

`TRIM` is introduced in SQL Server (starting with 2017).

In older version of SQL Server to perform trim you have to use `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` like following.

```
DECLARE @ss varchar(60)
  SET @ss = ' admin '

  select RTRIM(LTRIM(@ss))
```

If you don't like using `LTRIM`, `RTRIM` everywhere, you can create your own custom function like following.

```
   CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TRIM(@string NVARCHAR(max))
    RETURNS NVARCHAR(max)
     BEGIN
      RETURN LTRIM(RTRIM(@string))
     END
    GO
```

Comment: But it's not an older version - it's apparently SQL 2017. Unless they got the client tool mixed up

Comment: It seems someone mistakenly tagged 2017 by reading the first comment from a different user. OP never mentioned it is 2017. So I am assuming it is some older version.

Comment: Ah I see. I assume the OP will never return to clear it up so I will see if can edit the question and remove it

Comment: I'm an amateur in SQL. Although I have defined the function, I wonder why I cannot use `TRIM` as it always said `'trim' is not a recognized built-in function name.`
Turned out I have to use it like this `dbo.TRIM`.

Comment: @LamLe T-SQL requires UDF call-sites to be schema-qualified (i.e. your `CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TRIM` must be called as `dbo.TRIM` and not `TRIM`) because of how SQL Server resolves unqualified identifiers - it's not ideal, but the alternative is worse. Read this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1221/why-cant-i-call-my-udf-directly-why-do-i-need-to-qualify-it-3-levels-deep

Answer (score 26):

Perhaps it's set to an earlier compatibility level.

Use this to find out:

```
SELECT compatibility_level FROM sys.databases
```

SQL Server 2017 is *140*

If it's any lower then it won't recognize `TRIM`

To change the compatibility to SQL Server 2017

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name   
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 140
```

For a list of supported compatibility levels for each SQL Server version check out  [ALTER DATABASE (Transact-SQL) Compatibility Level.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-2017)

Based on comments below, your installed version of SQL Server is SQL 2016. You need to install SQL Sever 2017 to get `TRIM`

Comment: You might want to add the link to [ALTER DATABASE (Transact-SQL) Compatibility Level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-2017). It has a list of supported compatibility levels for each SQL Server version.

Comment: You’re right that would be helpful. I did google this entire answer and hopefully the OP can do that himself! Feel free to edit!

Comment: Setting compatibility level errors with Msg 15048, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Valid values of the database compatibility level are 100, 110, 120, or 130.

Comment: I am using MS SqlServer Management Studio 17.0 and 18.1 and both are having this issue.  The COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL IS 130 but when I try to set it up to 140, I get error "Valid values of the database compatibility level are 100, 110, 120, or 130."

Comment: Then basically your installation doesn’t support that level. You need to install a newer version.  You can see this in the link in my answer.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid When I test this on SQL 2017 with compatibility level 100, it works - I believe the compatibility level is not the cause, just the server version

Comment: I do appreciate any and all clarification supplied. There is a lot of confusion and activity on this abandoned question. At this stage no one knows the original SQL version or the compatibility level of the original question so who knows what the issue was.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid definitely a shame when a poster abandons the followup.  Almost certainly they were on an earlier version than 2017 (but as you say, who knows!)

Answer (score 6):

You can use this code for older versions:

```
SELECT RTRIM (LTRIM (' JKL ')) AS Trimmed
```

Which results in `'JKL'`

Comment: And that's (and many many other things) we know that SQL Server really sucks! That's the way Microsoft does things: why make it simple if we can complicate it at all!